# Clone only space in use from hard disk

Tags: linux, hard-drive, clone, dd, clonezilla

Can I use dd, rsync, clonezilla or any tool to clone only space in use in my hard disk in Linux? I need to do a backup from a 1 TB HD (with only 2 GB space in use) into a 500 GB HD.

Comment: No, you would need to use a file copy rather than a block copy or cloning tool.

Comment: I'm not sure, but partclone might let you do this.

Comment: You can also consider [this unix.SE answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/75590/318461).

Answer (score 37):

You can, but you should prepare your disk first. The trick is to use sparse file or compression. **This method is time consuming, it generates high I/O. In your case (2GB in use on 1 TB HDD) a file copy (as suggested in sawdust's comment) will probably be a way better solution.** If – on the other hand – you had e.g. 850 GB in use out of 1 TB, many small files therein, you wanted to backup MBR, partition table, metadata, all that at once – then my method would be a reasonable way to save at least 150 GB on the image file (which still couldn't fit into 500 GB HDD, unless the data compressed well enough).

**I'm writing this for users with higher disk usage.** Also note that the source drive should be healthy and allow to overwrite the empty space. I'm giving the solution mainly for backup, not recovery nor forensics. The time and I/O cost will be paid not only during image creation but also when (if) the image is written back to disk. **Think twice if the method is right for you.**

Let's say you need to clone `/dev/sdb` and there are several partitions: `/dev/sdb1`, `/dev/sdb2`…

### Preparation

To take high advantage of sparse files or compression you should overwrite the empty space with zeros. In case of Windows partition there may be some trouble due to Windows hibernation, read [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/145902).

If the source drive was an SSD, then it might be enough to use `fstrim` for every filesystem in it. Otherwise (and certainly in case of a HDD) you need to physically write zeros. This is how you can do it:

```
## Most commands need sudo.
mount -o rw /dev/sdb1 /mnt
dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/zero_file bs=32M
## Long wait here. Expect the following outcome: (which means that all empty space was zeroed)
### dd: error writing '/mnt/zero_file': No space left on device
sync
rm /mnt/zero_file
umount /dev/sdb1
## Repeat this with /dev/sdb2, /dev/sdb3 etc.
```

If there are major gaps in the partition layout then you should also fill them up with zeros. Swap partitions (if any) need special treatment in order to make the resulting image as small as possible. The Windows files like `hiberfil.sys`, `pagefile.sys` and `swapfile.sys` may be removed before `zero_file` creation. I won't cover these cases in detail here.

### Sparse file method

This method may be used if the target filesystem (where the image file will be saved) supports sparse files. To generate a sparse image file, invoke:

```
## dd probably needs sudo here.
dd if=/dev/sdb of=/foo/bar/my_image.dd bs=512 conv=sparse
```

(EDIT: originally there was `bs=32M` but it's not the good choice with `conv=sparse`. Compare [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1136357/432690).)

To write the image back:

```
## dd probably needs sudo here.
dd if=/foo/bar/my_image.dd of=/dev/sdb bs=32M
```

Advantages:

- The image may be mounted (`mount -o offset=…` or use `kpartx`) to access the files within.

Disadvantages:

- Target filesystem must support sparse files.
- You should remember to keep it sparse while copying (`cp --sparse=always`).

### Compressed file method

To generate the image:

```
## dd probably needs sudo here.
dd if=/dev/sdb bs=32M | gzip -c > /foo/bar/my_image.dd.gz
```

To write the image back:

```
## dd probably needs sudo here.
gzip -cd < /foo/bar/my_image.dd.gz | dd of=/dev/sdb bs=32M
```

These commands might be built without `dd`, with `gzip` only. I used `dd` to ensure 32 MiB buffer.

Advantages:

- The resulting file is non-sparse, it needs no special treatment.
- The image size will be reduced even more if the files on your source disk are prone to compression.

Disadvantages:

- It is hard to access the files within the compressed image without full decompression (some FUSE may be useful, although I'm not sure, never tried; consider a [squashfs approach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/75590/108618)).

---

### Hints

- Long after I wrote the first version of this answer I learnt there is [`virt-sparsify`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/libguestfs-tools/virt-sparsify.1.en.html) tool. It looks useful.
- To compress fast use `gzip --fast`, to compress best use `gzip --best`. Refer to `man gzip` for more options.
- Use `pigz` instead of `gzip` if you can. This should speed things up, because `pigz` can utilize more than one processor core. You can use another compressor if you like.
- To monitor the progress invoke `dd` with `status=progress` operand. If `dd` is already running without it (e.g. your `dd` doesn't support `status=progress` or you forgot to use it), send `USR1` signal to the tool (this doesn't kill the running `dd` command):

  ```
    kill -s USR1 $(pidof dd)
  ```

  and repeat as needed.
- As an alternative to `dd` you may use `pv` to read. Examples:

  ```
   pv -B 32m /dev/sdb | dd of=/foo/bar/my_image.dd bs=512 conv=sparse
   pv -B 32m /dev/sdb | gzip -c > /foo/bar/my_image.dd.gz
  ```

Comment: Thanks  for sharing such an awesome answer.  Something I noticed that you might want to mention is that **ls** and **du** will report different file sizes when constructing images that are sparse.  As far as I can tell **dd** will report the larger of the two sizes, as does **ls** however **du** will print a more accurate size of the file as it exists on the file system.

Comment: @Cadoiz [I'm not convinced about `sync,noerr`](https://superuser.com/a/1075837/432690). If with [`iflag=fullblock`](https://superuser.com/a/1388089/432690) then yes.

Comment: Thanks for the note. I updated my comment and referenced answer accordingly. To the `dd` commands you could add `conv=sync,noerror iflag=fullblock` for error safety - it is especially about skipping bytes. Repeatedly checking the current progress using `kill`, may be solved like this: `watch kill -USR1 $pid`. You can consider my answer here for more detail: https://superuser.com/a/1523120/910769

Comment: Is it a problem during the "Sparse file method" to use different bs for the first and second invocation? Or only when piped? Reference: "If you do this and specify a blocksize, make sure you use the same blocksize on each invocation." (The respective post is also worth reading: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/144178/318461 )

Comment: `cat` could also be considered instead of `dd` - [check this](https://tecmint.com/backup-or-clone-linux-partitions-using-cat-command)

Comment: Using `zstd --no-progress` was **62% faster** (16½ min.) over `dd bs=512 conv=sparse` (44 min.) for a 256GB NVMe drive with only 12% partitioned space, written to a SATA rotational drive (after first zeroing the unpartitioned space). `zstd --adapt` was a little slower, thus stick to default zstd compression.

Comment: This won't work when copying to another disk directly. `dd` is a poor tool for this job: if you copy a 1TB disk to a 2TB one, the 2TB will end up with a partition table that only allocates the space that was in the original disk (i.e. 1TB).

Answer (score 2):

If the target disk is already formatted, the second disk is plugged into the same machine as the first, is mounted, and if you're running Linux or Mac:

```
rsync -avP --ignore=/media/disk2 / /media/disk2
```

If the target disk is already formatted, the second disk is formatted and mounted into another PC, and if you're running Linux or Mac:

```
rsync -avP / user@ip_of_disk2_host:/media/disk2
```

This assumes you're just wanting a backup of the files without regard to the underlying drive.  This does a PER FILE backup and will run rather quickly on only 2 GB of data.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a pretty good answer already using gzip or sparse stuff, but it is quite contrived. The discussions of pros and cons in the answer is really worth it!

I may add [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/120124/how-to-copy-sd-card-whithout-copying-the-unallocated-space/120154#120154) reply about dealing with SD card backups on raspberry pi, which has the same problem of possible huge disk space overhead when using plain `dd`. The suggestion is to use `image-backup`, which sounds totally up to the task needed by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Use the right tool for the job, in this case [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/). Yes, the English is amateurish, but at least it attempts to resize partitions when cloning disks, to extend smaller drives onto larger drives. Clonezilla comes as a live ISO image that bundles and uses [Partclone](https://partclone.org/) to clone partitions.

The problem with dd is that it will blindly copy everything from one disk to another, including the partition table. This means that if you copy a 1TB disk to a 2TB disk, only 1TB of the larger disk will be used. Clonezilla specifically tries to extend the partition "proportionally" on the larger disk.

There's a problem when copying encrypted partitions though: since LUKS encryption is at the disk level, Clonezilla can't know which space is free and which is not, so it has to copy the clone partition. (Of course, neither can `dd`.)

Answer (score -2):

1. Make a gparted live USB
2. Boot into gparted and resize partition down on original drive to 2+ gb
3. Copy over drive
4. Resize newly copied partition to its full size

Comment: Yeah, the "copy over drive" part is kind of the entire point of the Q. You missed that.