# Why didn't `dd conv=sparse` save space as I expected?

Tags: dd, buffer, sparsefile

I was going to make an image of my old USB drive. I had good reasons to expect there were some blocks filled with zeros on the device, so to save some space I used `conv=sparse` option:

```
dd if=/dev/sdb of=myusb.img conv=sparse bs=32M
```

However it saved me nothing:

```
$ ls -hls myusb.img
250M -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 250M Oct 18 21:31 myusb.img
```

I'm sure there are zero-filled blocks on the device. **Why didn't `dd conv=sparse` save space?**

---

Note I already know the answer (I think). I'm posting it below. The question is for future reference.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you are absolutely sure there were zero-filled blocks then the reason you saved no space was the large buffer you used. From `man dd`:

> `sparse` try to seek rather than write the output for NUL input blocks

You used `bs=32M`, so you needed a whole 32 MiB block of zeros at a right offset for the `conv=sparse` option to do its job if only just once.

The option `bs` sets `ibs` (input block size) and `obs` (output block size). While the manual mentions *input blocks*, it is actually the `obs` that matters.

Here are the results of some tests. (As I am the OP, I did the tests with the very same device.) Each file is named according to `<obs_used>.img` pattern. Pay attention to the first column:

```
$ ls -hlst *.img
250M -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 250M Oct 18 22:02 4M.img
250M -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 250M Oct 18 22:02 2M.img
249M -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 250M Oct 18 22:02 1M.img
248M -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 250M Oct 18 22:01 512K.img
248M -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 250M Oct 18 22:01 256K.img
247M -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 250M Oct 18 22:00 128K.img
247M -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 250M Oct 18 21:57 64K.img
247M -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 250M Oct 18 21:56 32K.img
246M -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 250M Oct 18 21:55 16K.img
246M -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 250M Oct 18 21:54 8K.img
246M -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 250M Oct 18 21:53 4K.img
246M -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 250M Oct 18 21:52 2K.img
246M -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 250M Oct 18 21:51 1K.img
246M -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 250M Oct 18 21:44 512.img
```

The conclusion is: you shouldn't use large `obs` with `conv=sparse` option. The common sector size is 512 bytes, so `bs=512` seems just right. Your command should have been:

```
dd if=/dev/sdb of=myusb.img conv=sparse bs=512
```

Comment: It's good to see the `sparse` option actually working, but the saving is so small that it doesn't seem worth the trouble. Maybe you should fill the free space on the old device with an all-0x00 file and then delete it, before actually dumping the image with dd?

Comment: @ChangQian [I know the trick](https://superuser.com/a/1097391/432690).

Comment: You wrote in the question that you had *"good reasons to expect there were some blocks filled with zeros"*, so at the end how can you explain the very small amount of saved space even with `bs=512`? What were your good reasons? Given the limited total size and the name you gave I can imagine that the source is a USB key? If yes, unless this is a brand new key or unless you have explicitly written a file full of zeros on it, I wouldn't expect many sectors containing only zeros.

Comment: @PierU Two or more blocks are "some blocks". After 6 years I don't remember the reasons. Why should I ever explain the very small amount of saved space? IMO the fact it's "small" does not change the conclusion that smaller `bs` seems better when `conv=sparse` is used.

Comment: Your question/answer has been linked from another question to support the idea that `conv=sparse` would not save a significant amount of written blocks, without taking into account that the context in not the same (this is a SSD involved, so there are reasons to expect a different behavior compared to a USB key that has likely not even a garbage collection mechanism). You're not responsible for such wild extrapolation, but nonetheless it would be useful IMHO to update your answer and comment about the amount of saved space.