# Is it safe to use `dd conv=sparse` to migrate my system to a new SSD?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, dd

Back when HDDs were dominant, it's common to use the `dd` command to migrate system disks. But that creates a problem with SSDs: unused space from the source disk will also be written once, with either zeros or garbage. SSDs don't like that; they need to know which sectors hold really useful data.

Yes, I know I could do a `fstrim` or Optimize Disk after the migration, but that approach is imperfect: partition gaps, reserved partitions (like MSR), and space allocated but never actually written to (NTFS MFT/btrfs metadata/GlobalReserve/ext4 inode space?) cannot be trimmed. As an enthusiast I'd like to find a way not to mis-allocate one MiB on my new shiny SSD.

Then I came across the `conv=sparse` option of the `dd` command. Seems that by doing a `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=4K conv=sparse`, one could skip all unused sectors when moving data from old SSD to new SSD, assuming that both has the Deterministic Read Zeros after TRIM feature. But will that create new problems? For example, some database redo-log files are inherently packed with 0s, then will it create errors if a sector of 0s is allocated in the OS but not in the underlying flash storage?

Any insights are welcome.

Comment: `will it create errors if a sector of 0s is allocated in the OS but not in the underlying flash storage` Of course NOT. Nothing on any level higher than where SSD controller is can tell if a logical block is mapped or unmapped.

Comment: According to [these tests](https://superuser.com/a/1136358/8672), `sparse` won't save a great deal.

Comment: @TomYan indeed "of course not", but not for the reason you are giving. The controller may well behave like this: *"The OS wants to read a logical sector that I haven't mapped on any physical sector, I'm going to tell him he's completely wrong"*. But it would be a mess, even `dd` would be unable to clone the disk at the black level.

Comment: @harrymc I'm the author if the linked tests. `sparse` can save from nothing to a lot, it depends on the input data in the first place. It so happened my input data in these tests did not allow to save much; but it could be different. Still I think the [link you gave](https://superuser.com/a/1136358/8672) may be helpful here: if the OP uses large `obs` then they will probably save less than they would with smaller `obs`.

Comment: @PierU What are you even talking about? Have you misunderstood my point or what? I have no idea what you mean "may well behave like this". So you have bought some drive that comes with a warning like "don't read the part of the drive that hasn't been written or has been TRIM'd, otherwise the read will get you an I/O error instead of zeroes / pattern / old data"?

Comment: @TomYan I just point out that the reason you are giving is not  the right one.

Comment: @PierU I suppose you *thought* that I meant `conv=sparse` will have no effect anyway, and no, I wasn't trying to say that at all. What I mean is whether the logical block is mapped behind the scene will not determine whether normal read will succeed or fail. Or maybe you are trying to say "things are still possible even when they could never happen", idk. (By things I mean like drives that are insane by design.)

Comment: The use of the `conv=sparse` option here entirely relies on the assumption that any SSD always returns zeros when the OS wants to read a logical sector that has been trimmed. While it seem to be a common behavior, I am not sure this can be garanteed.

Comment: Yes, and I've said nothing that is even related to that. And the OP obviously knows that *working* RZAT is a requirement for it to work as desired.

Comment: (1) Your concern about packs of zeros that are useful data is justified. I think in general you need to `blkdiscard` the whole SSD prior to `dd conv=sparse`. (2) Unless you're totally sure the source drive is fully healthy, [GNU `ddrescue`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/572247/108618) is better than `dd`. Unfortunately it doesn't let you use `--sparse` when writing to a block device, while `dd conv=sparse` simply works. I think with `ddrescue` you could achieve something similar by using `--generate-mode` in a clever way, but this requires reading the source file twice.

Comment: @TomYan in my previous comment was answering the OP, not you. About our argument I think that there is some misunderstanding, but the format of the comments is not convenient to sort it out.

Comment: A long discussion but no conclusion - or am I wrong? Wouldn't it be safer and surer to backup using a disk image utility that knows about sparse files and unallocated sectors (the later may imply the former)?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I think you meant `fstrim`. You don't need to `blkdiscard` a new drive and you certainly don't want to use it on a drive to clone from...

Comment: @TomYan I meant `blkdiscard` on the new SSD, *in general*, in case "new" means "not the old one", not necessarily "totally not used before". If `blkdiscard` is not needed for this particular SSD then it will be a harmless no-op.