# Environment variables in split's filter

Tags: linux, bash, shell

So, I am trying the contents of a large block device using `split` like so:

```
split --bytes 10M --numeric-suffixes --filter='cat | ssh root@$remote_ip "gzip >> /root/myfilecopy.gz"' /dev/myblockdev
```

But when I save the remote file name in an environment variable and use that variable in `split`'s `filter`, it does not work:

```
remote_file=/root/myfilecopy.gz
split --bytes 10M --numeric-suffixes --filter='cat | ssh root@$remote_ip "gzip >> $remote_file"' /dev/myblockdev
```

This is what I get:

```
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
bash: -c: line 0: `gzip >> '
split: with FILE=x00, exit 1 from command: cat | ssh root@192.168.0.105 "gzip >> $remote_file"
```

Looks like the environment variable is not expanded properly inside the filter command.

Any clue how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: No, split does that to each file resulting from the partitioning. So, cat will invoked on files 10MB each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Overcomplicated?

Variables aside for a moment. This is your basic code:

> ```
>  split --bytes 10M --numeric-suffixes --filter='cat | ssh root@$remote_ip "gzip >> /root/myfilecopy.gz"' /dev/myblockdev
> ```

First of all: [`cat` is useless here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#UUOC_(Useless_Use_Of_Cat)).

Next I think that appending the results of consecutive `gzip`-s to the same file (`>>`) cancels the work of `split`. In theory at the end what you get is just gzipped `/dev/myblockdev`, exactly as if you did:

```
ssh root@$remote_ip 'gzip > /root/myfilecopy.gz' < /dev/myblockdev
```

In practice I would think of race condition. I do expect `split` to run `ssh`-s in sequence on the local side; but I wouldn't be surprised if in some circumstances various buffers or lags on the remote side caused the next `gzip` begin to write before the previous one finished. This would corrupt `myfilecopy.gz`. Opening the file just once prevents this.

If you used `$FILE` (see `man 1 split`) and wrote to multiple files, I would see the point of using `split`. Note this wouldn't introduce a race condition because each of these files would be opened just once.

Conclusion: `split` is probably useless, `cat` is useless for sure; careless appending may corrupt the resulting file.

---

#### The issue you asked about

OK, let's assume you have your reasons to use `split` and `>>` this way (your `cat` is still useless though).

Your current shell knows the value of `$remote_file`, but `split` and its filter(s) are child processes and they won't inherit the variable unless you `export` it beforehand. Nonexisting variable expands to nothing, so the relevant fragment looks like `gzip >> (newline)`, hence the error.

The same applies to `$remote_ip`. I guess in your code you don't use `$remote_ip` but the actual IP address `192.168.0.105`. From now on I use `remote_ip` as a *placeholder* (i.e. not a shell variable) for the actual IP address.

To `export`:

```
remote_file="/root/myfilecopy.gz"
export remote_file
# now your split command should utilize the variable as you expected
```

Alternatively you can make your current shell expand `$remote_file` at the moment you run `split`. Originally the `$remote_file` string is left intact because of single quotes surrounding it. The following syntax changes the type of quotes just for this one variable:

```
split --bytes 10M --numeric-suffixes --filter='ssh root@remote_ip "gzip >> '"$remote_file"'"' /dev/myblockdev
#                                                     close a single quote ^              ^ and open again
#                                             variable inside double quotes ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This way `split` never gets literal `$remote_file`, it gets its value.

---

#### Another issue

If you had `remote_file="/root/myfile copy.gz"`, the space in the path would split it into two arguments on the remote side. For this reason the more robust approach requires additional quoting. This is the above "no export" approach with extra quotes (escaped with `\`):

```
split --bytes 10M --numeric-suffixes --filter='ssh root@remote_ip "gzip >> \"'"$remote_file"'\""' /dev/myblockdev
```

Let's strip it step by step. Among other arguments, `split` would see the following as a single one:

```
--filter=ssh root@remote_ip "gzip >> \"/root/myfile copy.gz\""
```

It would run this filter in `bash`:

```
ssh root@remote_ip "gzip >> \"/root/myfile copy.gz\""
```

Then `ssh` would see this as one of its arguments:

```
gzip >> "/root/myfile copy.gz"
```

So on the remote side the redirection would be to `"/root/myfile copy.gz"`. Without these added quotes you would have:

```
gzip >> /root/myfile copy.gz
```

which is equivalent to

```
gzip copy.gz >> /root/myfile
```

---

#### Additional notes

- If the local side CPU is fast enough, consider `gzip` before `ssh`. This way you push less data through the network link(s); especially if you [prepared your block device to compress well](https://superuser.com/a/1097391/432690).
- If your intention was to run multiple `gzip` processes to get advantage from multiple CPU cores, then note they would probably run in sequence anyway; if not, a race condition -- you don't want this. Get familiar with `pigz`.