# how to dd HDD into network share over SSH into NAS on specific port and share?

Tags: hard-drive

pseudo code below, but how to do it? I dont have space to save dd image locally....

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/scp -P 12344 potato@10.10.45.44:/volume2/share02/01.dd
```

I don't know how to execute it or wrap it locally to go around low storage on the system that I try to dd image.

Comment: If you are trying to copy files to a NAS why not just use rsync.  `dd` doens't really help you in this case and presents the file size problem your now considering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can `scp`, you *probably* can run `cat` after you `ssh`.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda bs=4M | ssh -p 12344 potato@10.10.45.44 'cat > /volume2/share02/01.dd'
```

This may be troublesome if `sudo` and `ssh` both ask for your passwords. In this case make this `sudo` invocation run without password (`sudo true` just before may suffice); or `sudo su -` beforehand, so you're root and don't need `sudo` before `dd`; or make `ssh` not require password (use key-based authentication).

`dd` writes to its stdout, `ssh` takes it and passes to the remote `cat`, its output is redirected to `/volume2/share02/01.dd`.

Notes:

- While reading `/dev/sda` with `dd` it's good to use `bs=` larger than the default, e.g. `bs=4M`.
- I would use `dd status=progress …` or `pv` instead of `dd` (or at least between `dd` and `ssh`: `dd … | pv | ssh …`) to see the progress.
- Remember `sda` must not be written to while `dd` works. E.g. mounted `sda1` (unless read-only) may make the image inconsistent.
- You can reduce the size of the image. Read [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1097391/432690). In your case, after you prepare the whole `sda`, the command may be

  ```
  pv /dev/sda | gzip -c -9 | ssh -p 12344 potato@10.10.45.44 'cat > /volume2/share02/01.dd.gz'
  ```