# error writing 'wipefile': No space left on device

Tags: ubuntu, vmware

I have a question. I have Vmware workstation and one of my Vms is nextcloud with ubuntu 1804.

I like to have a snappy instance so I use these commando's found here:

```
sudo e4defrag /                         
dd if=/dev/zero of=wipefile bs=1M; sync; rm wipefile            
sudo vmware-toolbox-cmd disk shrinkonly
```

For a while this worked fine.
But now on step 2: `dd if=/dev/zero of=wipefile bs=1M; sync; rm wipefile`
I get error:

```
64172396544 bytes (64 GB, 60 GiB) copied, 56.5438 s, 1.1 GB/s
ncadmin@cloud:~$ error writing 'wipefile': No space left on device
```

But when I do a: df -Th I have plenty of space:

```
Filesystem                        Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                              devtmpfs  3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                             tmpfs     796M  1.4M  794M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ext4      103G   39G   60G  40% /
tmpfs                             tmpfs     3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                             tmpfs     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                             tmpfs     3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                         ext4      976M  157M  753M  18% /boot
/dev/loop0                        squashfs   89M   89M     0 100% /snap/core/739            6
/dev/loop1                        squashfs   55M   55M     0 100% /snap/lxd/1210            0
/dev/loop2                        squashfs   55M   55M     0 100% /snap/lxd/1198            5
/dev/loop3                        squashfs   90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/771            3
tmpfs                             tmpfs     796M     0  796M   0% /run/user/1000
```

I only have basic linux understanding

Comment: Are you 100% sure the error comes from step 3 and not from step 2?

Comment: ur right. step 2. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

`No space left on device` was expected. This command

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=wipefile bs=1M
```

reads from `/dev/zero` and writes to `wipefile`. The special file `/dev/zero` cannot be depleted. The command runs until `wipefile` cannot grow anymore (or until you manually terminate it first).

So you clogged the filesystem, there was indeed `no space left on device`. Then you flushed cache with `sync` and removed the file with `rm`. The file was exactly `64172396544` bytes before removal, this space was reclaimed when you removed the file. Now you have about 60 GiB available on `/`. All fits.

The point of creating this file was to fill available space with zero bytes; the point of syncing was to make sure all zeros actually got to the device; the point of removing the file was to formally mark zeroed blocks as empty again. You didn't need the file itself; you needed to write zeros to "empty" blocks. A file that later gets removed is just a simple way to do it.

I guess `vmware-toolbox-cmd` can now do its job: shrink. I don't know this tool at all but the idea of filling empty space with zeros is quite sane when you keep (or want to keep) the entire filesystem as a file and you want the file to be as small as possible. The main filesystem of your VM is just a file from the point of view of the host, right? Compare [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1097391/432690) where the same method is used to prepare a filesystem to be effectively stored as a regular file. My code explicitly says

> ```
> ## Long wait here. Expect "no space left on device".
> ```

Comment: Super answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thank you so much. As a linux user with a basic knowledge, I need to let this sink in :-) because how do I proceed on this? 

Do I need to fill it with zeros, or should the step 3 of shrinking be enough? And skip step 2. 
   
This is for me a good example that you need to understand the commands before executing them.                                                                    

It crashed my entire nextcloud server. Lucky for me it was only my private server and not a production server.

Comment: @roT- I expect the step 3 to be most effective after you fill the empty space with zeros; less effective (or not effective at all in extreme cases) if you don't.